# basic python condition checking for input, always setting to input of 1

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Edit:
I'm trying to check the user input against a array of allowed inputs to get a if statement to execute, a simple if you enter `'y' or 'yes' or 1` the code will run, i think i'm using the wrong constructs. :(

I have a really simple peiece of code that is meant to run user input against multiple possible conditions in a predefined array:

```
from spiders import test

run_test_spider = 0
condition = [1, 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES', 'y', 'Y']
x=-1
def spiders():

    for run_test_spider in condition:
        global x
        x=x+1
        if run_test_spider == condition[x]:
            test.main()
            print 'gotcha!'
        print 'running.......'
    print run_test_spider
    print 'hello'



print 'hello would you like to run a test spider?'
print '1,yes,y = Yes I do!!!'
print '0,no,n  = Nope!'
run_test_spider = raw_input(': ')

spiders()
```

I ran the debugger (pydev) in eclipse and once I input the string `n` to get a failed condition check, the debugger tells me the input automatically becomes `1`, which causes the code to always execute the spider

does anyone know why my inputs are all becoming `1`?

This `1` business is what eclipse is showing in its variables field, when I enter the input (once I step the debugger up to that point)

also the console spits out this: when I enter the input during debug:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.5.0.2012040618\pysrc\pydevd_comm.py", line 755, in doIt
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluateExpression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.5.0.2012040618\pysrc\pydevd_vars.py", line 384, in evaluateExpression
    result = eval(compiled, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

Comment: So you're checking if each item of `condition` is in `condition`?

Comment: Opps, cut of some code, the debugger view is a bit small :)

Comment: You actually never use the input value..

Comment: i'm trying to check, that if the user inputs y, or yes, or 1, then the code in the if statement executes, or at least that what i'm trying to do

Comment: @Tisho, really, that's embarrassing. am i misusing the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for run_test_spider in condition:
```

means that run_test_spider will be initialized with each element in condition.
So you actually check if each item of `condition` is in it...

EDIT: So this is your check:

```
condition = [1, 'yes' 'y']

def spiders():

    if run_test_spider.lower() in condition:
        test.main()
        print 'gotcha!'
```

Comment: run_test_spider is just a input variable, it takes a string. What variable would item be? my variable x?

Comment: Mate, thanks a lot!, `if run_test_spider in condition:` is exactly what I needed. it works perfectly. I made `1` a string instead in `condition` and everything is good. cheers mate :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not send the input from the user to the command you want to use it in. To use it pass the  run_test_spider as input to the spider command and, declare the command to accept the input
2. Do not reassign run_test_spider in the for loop.
3. To conveniently check if an item is in a list, you can simply use the construct `if a in b: <do something>`
4. Finally, as pointed by @Tisho, raw_input returns a string, so make the `1` in your code a string: `'1'`

So, the code becomes:

condition = ['1', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES', 'y', 'Y']

```
def spider(run_test_spider):
   if run_test_spider in conditions:
            # do something
   else:
            # do something else

run_test_spider = raw_input(':')
spider(run_test_spider)
```